# Favicon icon magento2

Tags: magento2

i have add manually fav icon

and upload  fav magento_theme web image favicon.ico

but not showing

Comment: Please try to upload it from the backend. Admin login >> content >> Configuration >> Edit your theme >> HTML head >> upload favicon >> Save and dont forget to clear your browser and magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

To override the default 16px x 16px favicon manually, add your custom favicon.ico in the **app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/web/directory**

After uploading image run below command:

> php bin/magento bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

for more reference please check this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/favicon.html)